# How to make display the code as code after pasting the code in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pretty-print

I want to display the code as code by **onkeyup event** in the textarea **which something looks like online compilers without compiling anything**, I'm using `code-prettify` which is this lib :     `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>`

What I want to do when the user pastes his code in the textarea the code appears as code

the way it appears in one is by using `prettyprint` class:     `<pre class="prettyprint"> <code class="prettyprint  "> <p> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>`

**I don't mind using any other libraries**

[image]

Comment: whats your question?

Comment: then what's the problem ?

Comment: What I want to do is make  the code appears as a code in the textarea which doesn't display as a code

Comment: did you use ```document.write()``` ?

Comment: `textarea` does not support that kind of formatting, you need a rich text input like TinyMCE

Answer (score 0):

Take reference from this and try to implement it according to your needs:
[Online coding playground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4447&v=AruJ23XlBps&feature=emb_logo)

you are required to integrate with [judge0](https://judge0.com/)